# Gradio: How do I programtically insert the loading icon in gr.Chatbot

Tags: gradio

In gradio, when using gr.Chatbot, a loading icon that looks like the image below shows up when you engage the chatbot (see the image below).

Question: What is the best way to programatically show and hide this loading icon?

[image]